# Discovery pattern for REST API endpoint

Tags: java, node.js, rest, microservices

I m actually studying Microservice architecture pattern and it seems that the API Gateway pattern uses the Discovery pattern, but with REST API endpoints.

Can anybody explain me how it works for example if my API Gateway is NodeJS based and my REST APIs are Java written ?

I dont really know how can I implement this pattern and I dont find any code or schema to help me understand a bit more.

Thanks for advance

Comment: Can you give me further details about what you want to accomplish? (could not find anything about the discovery pattern, the api gateway pattern is here: http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html )

Comment: I have found the discovery pattern as well. http://microservices.io/patterns/server-side-discovery.html . The discovery is easy you need to check the request and forward to the proper instance. I guess a simple load balancer does just the same, so there is nothing new here.

Comment: I guess the API gateway and the discovery both can be solved with REST layered architecture. They are just layers on top of the services; some client type dependent message building and a load balancer, nothing special. The microservice is the same as CQRS + event sourcing. I don't know why we need this new terminology to describe already existing techniques, I guess these are abstractions and I was talking about concrete implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on an open format for API discovery. Its not associated with any existing gateway or proxy architecture. I'm just looking to create way to define the meta data for API operations, which includes machine readable definitions like API Blueprint, Swagger, etc. - http://apisjson.org. Let me know if you have any questions, or I can help further.